# How can I use solrj to do a query with spellcheck

Tags: solr, spell-checking, solrj

usually , we use http get method to do a spellcheck query, but now I have to use solrj to do this, pls help me to solve this question , thx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify all parameters via:

```
query.setParam("spellcheck", "true");
query.setParam("spellcheck.q", query);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the [code in the Wiki page](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolJava). I believe it does what you want.